# Google Geochart only appears after a refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to integrate Google GeoChart to my rails application. In the view i simply copied-pasted the example from Google:

On top of the document i have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['geochart'],
            // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
            // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
            'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Country', 'Popularity'],
            ['Germany', 200],
            ['United States', 300],
            ['Brazil', 400],
            ['Canada', 500],
            ['France', 600],
            ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Then I add the div with the id:

```
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

But i get the following error:

```
VM17084:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:3:21
    at o.assignNewBody (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at o.replaceBody (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
    at o.e.renderView (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at o.render (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at Function.e.render (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at t.renderSnapshot (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at t.render (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at r.render (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
```

The error disapears when I reload the page, which makes me thinks that it is related to Turbolinks.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue please ?

Comment: You might want to remove that api key if it's your real key.

Comment: Hey @zwippie, it is not my real key, it is the key from the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page wasn't fully loaded when your javascript code started to run, `google.charts` was not available yet, hence the `Cannot read property 'load' of undefined` error.

Solution: Wrap your javascript code in a listener that fires when the page is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  google.charts.load('current', {
    // ...etc...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['geochart'],
            // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
            // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
            'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

        function drawRegionsMap() {
            var rubydata = JSON.parse('<%= @user_origin.to_json.html_safe -%>')
            data = [["Country","Value"]].concat(rubydata)
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

            var options = {
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                colors: <%= raw @palette_final.to_json %>
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }    }, 1000);
```